# Multisite non www domain gives registration error but should redirect to www.domain.com

Tags: multisite, redirect

I'm running wordpress multisite, and when I connect to my domain at domain.com I get the error "Greetings Site Administrator! You are currently allowing “none” registrations. To change or disable registration go to your Options page."

Should I create a 301 redirect from non www to www.domain.com or is there a way to configure multisite to handle this redirect?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can make that happen in the .htaccess file. just add these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this will do a 301 from non-www to www of your domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `NOBLOGREDIRECT` to your `wp-config.php`. It redirects all non-existing subdomains to the defined link.

`define('NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://www.domain.com/');`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [WPMU domain mapping tool](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) to map the base domain to www.domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rely on a plugin or modify your .htaccess file ... the best permanent fix is to login to your Domain Registry and make sure you have both the www and the . records setup.

This means that the DNS will handle your www and .domain requests and you don't have to worry about that .