# WordPress Multisite Strange Redirect on Primary Site

Tags: multisite, redirect, homepage, domain, domain-mapping

I am using a plugin which allows for multiple TLD's with WordPress multi-site. ([WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)) No idea if this is a conflicting issue or not. Doubtfut, but thought I would throw it out there.

Every now and then, when I visit the primary website which multi-site was installed on, I get redirected to a page: `http://www.primarydomain.com/wp-signup.php?new=primarydomain.com`

Displaying the following text in a yellow box:

> Greetings Site Administrator! You are currently allowing “none”
>   registrations. To change or disable registration go to your Options
>   page.

and a string of text beneath that:

> Registration has been disabled.

Although, I already added `define('NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://www.primarydomain.com/');` to `wp-config.php`

Why is this happening?

Comment: Solution: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/36526/9579

Comment: Wasn't this a problem of `siteurl` being different from the `NOBLOGREDIRECT` value?

Comment: Nope, all sites were set as: "www.domain-name.com". The problem was none of the sites were redirecting non-www URLs to www URLs. If you accessed any of the site URLs without prefixing them with "www", then the site would redirect to the primary site's network registration page. My solution was to make sure that you have all non-www URLS redirecting to www URLs for all of your sites in the network.